# AWS SNS confirmSubscription API call not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-sns, subscribe

I am trying to subscribe my endpoint to an SNS https subscription. 
My code doesn't seem to be receiving SNS's POST request that sends the confirmation data. 
I am using Node with the express framework.

I have a feeling I'm not parsing the response correctly. 
I will attach my code.

Anyone see anything here that looks askew?
Any help is appreciated.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-east-1"
});

AWS.config.apiVersions = {
  sns: '2010-03-31'
};

var sns = new AWS.SNS();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('The GET is hitting');
  res.send(req.body);
});

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('THE BODY IS ', req);
  console.log('THE REQUEST BODY IS ', req.body);
  if(req.body.Type === 'SubscriptionConfirmation') {
    console.log("Subscription Confirmation Message--->"+req.body);
    sns.confirmSubscription({
      Token: req.body.Token,
      TopicArn: req.body.TopicArn,
      Type: req.body.Type
    });
      console.log('MESSAGE DATA IS ', req.body.Token);
    } else if (req.body.Type === 'Notification') {
      console.log('Notification has arrived')
    } else {
      console.log('Unexpected message ' + req.body)
    }
});
```

Comment: What output does this code generate?

Comment: It returns an empty object

Comment: Amazon sends plain text data.

A proper answer is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51509836/aws-sns-confirm-subscription-request-processing-issue